# divide and conquer with recursion

Tags: java

[Sample with input and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZI7d.jpg)I'm trying to apply the divide and conquer theorem on an array of integers in which I am to find the worst case index. On the initial array I have to split it into two on both sides of the midpoint. This is repeatedly done and at each instance the midpoint is deleted. I am to check for the peak on each sub array but in the end I am to print out only the indexes of all the worst cases. In as the input will be the initial length of the array at any given instance. So far I have been able to request and input and print out an array of indices of a given length n. Given that I'm not too familiar with Java yet I don't know how to go about it.

```
class Peak {


    public static void main(String a[]){
         List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("enter the length of the array: ");
            int n = s.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) 
            al.add(i);
            System.out.println(al);
            int size = al.size();

            if (al.size()%2==0) {
                 //Sublist to ArrayList


                 ArrayList<Integer> lhs = new ArrayList<Integer>(al.subList(0, (size  - 1)/2));
                 ArrayList<Integer> rhs = new ArrayList<>(al.subList((size + 1)/2, n));

            }

            if (al.size()%2==1) {
                 //Sublist to ArrayList
                 ArrayList<Integer> lhs = new ArrayList<Integer>(al.subList(0, (size  - 1)/2));
                 ArrayList<Integer> rhs = new ArrayList<>(al.subList((size + 1)/2, n));

            }
      }
```

Comment: Please provide sample of random input and the desired output.

Comment: I have included an image with the inputs and the desired output. Thanks